# how to access multiple instantiated object in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

when I'm instantiate some object and I create a reference for I destroy which destroy the only first object in instantiating, my goal is to declare how to create multiple references of instantiated object?, I'm trying this

```
 instiatedobject = GameObject.Instantiate(realobject, realobject.position, real.rotation);
```

Comment: What is "create multiple references of instantiated object" ? can you explain it ?

Comment: If you create multiple things you could keep a list of them or depending on why you need them find them at the required time

Answer (score 0):

You could use any generic collection type like `List`, `Queue` etc. For example

```
private List<GameObject> runtimeCreatedObjects;

private void Awake() {
    runtimeCreatedObjects = new List<GameObject>();
}

public void CreateObject() {
    GameObject instiatedobject = GameObject.Instantiate(realobject, realobject.position, real.rotation);
    runtimeCreatedObjects.Add(instiatedobject);
}
```

Here every time we instantiate new object we add it to our list and use them elsewhere as per our requirement.